# What is the proper way to structure build scripts within a CRA React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webstorm, create-react-app

I've built both Node.js servers, and React apps before, but I'm working on a project that requires some deployment scripting for the first time.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to have a script download a file locally and generate some json before my CRA React + Typescript build happens, in order to automate some functionality.

More generally though, I'm wondering what the best practice is for creating an arbitrary script (ideally in Typescript!) that can be run as a part of the build pipeline for a React app.

I assume this would be a node or node-ts script of some sort, but I can't figure out how to slot it into the project structure!

Bonus points if WebStorm will still be able to resolve any import/requires :)

Thanks!